# File pointer - sending and reception in a function

Tags: python, pointers, parameters, reference

Python 2.7
Download a test file from: www.py4inf.com/code/mbox.txt
Briefly, I need list all lines that start with 'From' and take only the mail address. Selecting line by line.
If the condition is true, write in other file the ( only) mail address (result). I could wrote the code and it is working. But It would be better if I use functions. I crashed when I tried to pass the parameters. I have a problem when I have a function that receive a parameter and send one or two.

The result is: copy line by line ALL input file in output file almost like a recursion. No search nothing and the file is very big.

At last, have you any page to read about funtions, paramt, passing paramt, pass reference, and other. Ask is easy and I prefer read and try to understand and if I have a problem, light a cande in the middle of the night!.

```
#Li is the input paramet. Line from fileRead(the pointer of the file).  
#if the condition is true select all lines that start with From:

def funFormat(li):
if li.startswith('From:'):
    li = li.rstrip('')
    li = li.replace('From: ',' \n')
    return li?

fileRead=open('mbox_small.txt','r')
for eachline in fileRead:
    result=funFormat(eachline)
    fileWrite =open('Resul73.txt', 'a')
    fileWrite.write( result )
fileRead.close()
fileWrite.close()
```

Comment: There is a slight indentation error. What does your function return when the if condition is false? How are you handling that?

Comment: Python does not have pointer types, and does not support pass-by-reference semantics. You should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening a file every time you need to write, and closing it just at the end. Maybe that's what's messing it up? Try this and let me know if it works -

```
#Li is the input paramet. Line from fileRead(the pointer of the file).  
#if the condition is true select all lines that start with From:

def funFormat(li):
    if li.startswith('From:'):
        li = li.rstrip('')
        li = li.replace('From: ',' \n')
        return li
    else:
        return None

fileRead = open('mbox_small.txt', 'r')
fileWrite = open('Resul73.txt', 'a')
for eachline in fileRead:
    result=funFormat (eachline)
    if result:
        fileWrite.write (result)
fileRead.close()
fileWrite.close()
```

Also, I suggest you to read up on with blocks. This will help you work with files more efficiently. As for functions, there are enough resources online.

Comment: Yeah !. Your answer is  working.

I think the biggest problem was, solved the "return none". Never contemplate that situation. ,And I have the bad habit of opening the file for writing within the cycles.
I come from C ++ and Python is so free to write code that I am trying to put order and understand the rules to write it. .
Thank you very much for your kind reply.

Comment: It is never a good habit to open files inside a loop and not close them, regardless of the language! :) Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. Will be helpful if someone faces the same problem later on.